# Двумерный массив со средним арифметическим столбцов

Tags: массивы, сортировка, алгоритм, pascal

Я должен найти среднее арифметическое положительных элементов каждого столбца матрицы `А[5, 4]` при условии, что в каждом столбце есть по крайней мере один положительный элемент.

Моя программа вычисляет среднее арифметическое не столбцов, а строк. Как её исправить?

```
program double_array;
const
   NumRows = 5;
   NumColumns = 4;
var
   matrix : array [1..NumRows, 1..NumColumns] of integer;
   arithmeticMean : array [1..NumColumns] of real;
   row, column : integer; 
   sum : real;
begin

   writeln('Enter your array');
      for row := 1 to NumRows do
        begin 
          writeln(' ');
          for column := 1 to 4 do
          readln( matrix [row, column] );
        end;

    for column := 1 to NumColumns do 
        begin
          sum := 0;
             for row := 1 to NumRows do 
               begin
                  if matrix[row, column] > 0 then begin
                     sum := sum + matrix[row, column]
               end
         end;
    arithmeticMean[column] := sum / NumRows;
    write ( arithmeticMean[column]:7:3 );
    end;

end.
```

Comment: В заголовках циклов for поменять row на column, column на row и так же поступить с NumColumns и NumRows

Comment: В Вашей программе к тому, что написал @alexis, отсутствует выход из столбца при обнаружении отрицательного элемента.